# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using spring boot + spring security + Rest API + JWT 
trying to configure the project to fetch values from psql database to authorise the user.

The application is getting started but I am getting following error at startup.

**Stack trace :**

```
    2018-06-29 12:32:47.943  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
    2018-06-29 12:32:47.943  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2018-06-29 12:32:48.050  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    2018-06-29 12:32:48.131  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    2018-06-29 12:32:48.141  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
    2018-06-29 12:32:48.142  INFO 19114 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@5bfd7478
    2018-06-29 12:32:48.486 ERROR 19114 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000302: Unable to construct current session context [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext]

    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildCurrentSessionContext(SessionFactoryImpl.java:975) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.iqdigi.ityrepro.SpringSecurityItyreProApplication.main(SpringSecurityItyreProApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

**pom with latest spring boot 2.0.3 :**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application properties :**

```
server.port:8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

What is missing? Do I need to more information to the question? I have looked for the answer but found none exact as this. 
I tried updating the maven and changing the hibernate version

Answer (score 3):

i encountered the same error. I however needed some libraries from the updated Springboot 2.0.3 Release so i removed the line

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

it's the class causing the exception and I have yet to find the updated version just in case i need session handling. I however prefer using @Transactional for session handling so no issue there